# How can I use multiple projects to separate a large ASP.NET MVC site into departments?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Suppose I have a very large site like amazon.com.  I’d like to use asp.net mvc for the whole site but having one large project with hundreds of contributors is not practical.  I’d like to split the work into projects like books, tools, toys, groceries, etc. for each department.  Then when they build and deliver a new release I can just drop the “books.dll” into the site and it all magically works.  I see this thing called “areas” but it looks like they’re still part of the same project.  I need something that could potentially be stored not just in a separate project but a separate TFS instance as well.  The departments would only ever come together on my test/production servers and hopefully just by dropping in DLLs.  Anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asp MVC 2 has support for Project Areas catering for this development scenario

More detail at [Phil Haack blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/10/01/asp.net-mvc-preview-2-released.aspx)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee307987%28VS.100%29.aspx is the actual answer.  Phil has good info so I'll give you the check.

Comment: Couple of notes:  1) Make sure you install the MVC 2 Preview 2, not just the MVC 2 Beta.  B) The directions at this link often say "area" when they mean project.

Comment: Looks like formal support for multiple projects will not be offered with this release.  "maybe" in a future release.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at **[areas](http://haacked.com/archive/0001/01/01/single-project-areas.aspx)** in ASP.NET MVC 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Shoulda looked harder before posting:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee307987%28VS.100%29.aspx
"Walkthrough: Creating an ASP.NET MVC Areas Application Using Multiple Projects"

(self-slap!)

Comment: trying it out now.  Gotta get the latest preview.