# Can I create an ASP.NET MVC 2 project with multiple areas without referencing each Child in the parent area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, version-control, build-process

This is a follow-up question to my original query: 
[How can I use multiple projects to separate a large ASP.NET MVC site into departments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791605/how-can-i-use-multiple-projects-to-separate-a-large-asp-net-mvc-site-into-departm)

Now that I have this working, is there a way to still have multiple project but not have to reference each child area from the parent project?  Ideally I'd like to be able to have multiple, separate and distinct projects that only come together on the production/test machines.  I should be able to build and test each "area" separately.

Comment: Looks like the answer is "not right now."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in MVC 2 Beta.  Perhaps a future release.