# Does the visual studio 2008 Web Server supports multiple projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I have an mvc site with two projects.  One is the site itself and then a second project contains controls which are content only.  The reason for this is that the control project is for elements that live in a cms.  When I am running it locally in dev studio, I would like to be able to load these controls without setting up iis.

Is there anyway that the visual studio web server can recognize this second project as a different virtual directory so I can use functions like MapPath("~/cms/file.ascx") to load these elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in a supported fashion.
[Can I create an ASP.NET MVC 2 project with multiple areas without referencing each Child in the parent area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862577/can-i-create-an-asp-net-mvc-2-project-with-multiple-areas-without-referencing-eac)

MVC Preview 2 has support but it has been pulled from the final version.

Comment: Bummer! I saw that they had areas in preview 1 and then ripped it out.